# .Net Core MVC - Attribute routing and building query string using custom anchor tag helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my .Net Core 2.1 application, I have to pass few query string parameters between pages (several pages). So I created a custom tag helper to build these URLs with required parameters to avoid coding these parameters behind every anchor tag in my layout.

Later I added attribute routing to my controller methods to make the URLs SEO. But these anchor tags don't resolve/match with the routes because it doesn't find the required parameters to match the route path. My work around is to get rid of the custom tag helper and pass the parameters in the built-in tag helper.

Any thoughts on how to make the route attributes work with custom tag helpers?

**UPDATE**: 
-------------------------Custom Tag Helper-------------------------

```
[HtmlTargetElement("mya",Attributes =ForAttributeName)]
public class MyAnchorTagHelper : AnchorTagHelper
{
   private const string ForAttributeName = "my-a";

   public ExtAnchorTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator) {}
   public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
   {
        RouteValues.Add("Param1", "xyz");
        RouteValues.Add("Param2", "abc");
        RouteValues.Add("Param3", "jkl");
        ---------some other code here------------------
        output.TagName = "a";
        base.Process(context, output);
   }
```

-------------------------Route Attribute-------------------------

```
namespace App.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    [Route("{param1}/{param2}/{param3}")]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public MyController() {}
        [Route("student",Name ="ManageStudent")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           return View();
        }
```

-------------------------Code from the View/Layout-------------------------

```
<mya my-a="x" asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="My" asp-action="Index" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
     <i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-user"></i>Students
</mya>
```

Comment: Can you maybe show some example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Added some code, incomplete though. Hope it helps.